# Using COUNT on two MySQL fields (then need the sum of the two fields)

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query which works fine to give me the Count of the "smconnectivity_b" field.

We added in a second field called: "smconnectivity_c" which can also have values.

I need to include any of these new values in the same Count logic below:

```
    SELECT smconnectivity_b, COUNT(smconnectivity_b) AS Used, LEFT(smconnectivity_b, 4) AS Collo, 144 - COUNT(smconnectivity_b) AS Available, concat(round(( COUNT(smconnectivity_b)/144 * 100 ),1),'%') AS percentage, (round(( COUNT(smconnectivity_b)/144 * 100 ),1)) AS percentage2,

CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(smconnectivity_b) >= 25 AND COUNT(smconnectivity_b) < 121 THEN 'Yellow'
        WHEN COUNT(smconnectivity_b) >= 121 AND COUNT(smconnectivity_b) < 145 THEN 'Red'

ELSE 'Green'
END AS Color

FROM     tblsplicemapping

GROUP BY smconnectivity_b
ORDER BY smconnectivity_b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your query would probably be faster like this:

```
SELECT  smconnectivity_b, Used, 
        LEFT(smconnectivity_b, 4) AS Collo, 144 - Used AS Available,
        concat(round(( Used/144 * 100 ),1),'%') AS percentage, 
        (round(( Used/144 * 100 ),1)) AS percentage2,
        CASE 
        WHEN Used >= 25 AND Used < 121 THEN 'Yellow'
        WHEN Used >= 121 AND Used < 145 THEN 'Red'
        ELSE 'Green' END AS Color

FROM (
    SELECT smconnectivity_b, count(*) AS Used
        FROM     tblsplicemapping
        GROUP BY smconnectivity_b
    ) subselect
ORDER BY smconnectivity_b
```

Now...

> We added in a second field called: "smconnectivity_c" which can also have values. I need to include any of these new values in the same Count logic below

You can't really do that in this query. The simplest would be to make two separate queries. If you want to combine them, you can always use UNION ALL.

Comment: How do I exclude NULLS?

Comment: Add a WHERE smconnectivity_b IS NOT NULL?

Comment: that will work.. but placement was the real question. will try before the GROUP BY, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @peufeu I have updated the query & used UNION ALL to combine the two field counts. thanks.

Here is the final updated query:

```
(SELECT  smconnectivity_b, Used, 
        LEFT(smconnectivity_b, 4) AS Collo, 144 - Used AS Available,
        concat(round(( Used/144 * 100 ),1),'%') AS percentage, 
        (round(( Used/144 * 100 ),1)) AS percentage2,
        CASE 
        WHEN Used >= 25 AND Used < 121 THEN 'Yellow'
        WHEN Used >= 121 AND Used < 145 THEN 'Red'
        ELSE 'Green' END AS Color

FROM (
    SELECT smconnectivity_b, count(*) AS Used
        FROM     tblsplicemapping
        GROUP BY smconnectivity_b
    ) subselect
)

UNION ALL

(SELECT  smconnectivity_c AS smconnectivity_b, Used, 
        LEFT(smconnectivity_c, 4) AS Collo, 144 - Used AS Available,
        concat(round(( Used/144 * 100 ),1),'%') AS percentage, 
        (round(( Used/144 * 100 ),1)) AS percentage2,
        CASE 
        WHEN Used >= 25 AND Used < 121 THEN 'Yellow'
        WHEN Used >= 121 AND Used < 145 THEN 'Red'
        ELSE 'Green' END AS Color

FROM (
    SELECT smconnectivity_c, count(*) AS Used
        FROM     tblsplicemapping
        GROUP BY smconnectivity_c
    ) subselect
)
ORDER BY smconnectivity_b
```